# OpenGL: how to clip a 2D area to avoid text with GlutBitmap to be printed out of this area?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

How can I define in my app some areas where text can be printed, without overflowing out of them?

```
int printText(char *myChar, int color, double x, double y, double z)
{
    call_color(color);
    int end_of_char=strlen(myChar);
    glRasterPos3d(x,y,-1);
    for(int i=0;i<end_of_char;i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,myChar[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

sample:

```
void window_function()
{
    // printing things before on all screen
    // define clipping aera
    char tem[64];
    sprintf(tem,"mouse x: %.4f mouse y: %.4f",mouse_ox,mouse_oy);
    printText(tem,COL_LIGHT_GREY,x+0.005,y-0.085,1.0);
    //re opening the clipping aera to the complete screen
    //printing other stuff    
}
```

Comment: You can use [stencil buffer](https://open.gl/depthstencils).

Comment: Or you can limit the drawable area using `glViewport`. But be aware that you will also have to adjust the projection matrix.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot  what would the best way to handle windows self made creation, where i need to move inside in x and y the point of view ?

Answer (score 1):

[`glScissor()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glScissor.xhtml) + `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`.